# sumproduct sumifs -- formula works in excel not in google sheet

Tags: excel, google-sheets-formula, sumifs, sumproduct

I have been struggling with a formula that works in excel but not in google sheet. Objective is to get the sum of amounts provided in different currencies.

=SUMPRODUCT(B7:B12,SUMIFS(F:F,E:E,C7:C12))

B7:B12 contains amounts in different currencies
C7:C12 contains the currency code for each amount
E has the list of currency codes
F has the exchange rate for each currency
thank you much for any help/support!

[sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJZoE.png)
-- exactly the same data and formula in XL and GS

Comment: Do you have actual sample data and expected results to work with?

Comment: In google sheet it will depends on `SUMIFS()` result. Sumifs() result must be same size of first array of sumproduct.

Comment: Are the arguments in sumifs() the same in googlesheets as in Excel?

Comment: @JvdV added in my text the sample data. Data and formula are exactly the same in both documents. And indeed I have an error message in GS about the size of the array which does however work with XL.

Comment: `=SUMPRODUCT(VLOOKUP(B1:B6,D1:E2,2,1)*A1:A6)` then?

Comment: @JvdV  :-)  Thank you so much, this is it. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately at time of writing Sumifs doesn't expand in Google Sheets even when wrapped in Arrayformula. If you try it on its own you get:

```
=ArrayFormula(SUMIFS(F:F,E:E,C7:C12))
```

[image]

whereas if you try the same conditions with Sumif you get:

```
=ArrayFormula(sumif(E:E,C7:C12,F:F))
```

[image]

which is why you get the error.

One way to fix it is to use Sumif instead of sumifs:

```
=ArrayFormula(sumproduct(B7:B12,sumif(E:E,C7:C12,F:F)))
```

[image]

EDIT

Array formula can be omitted if wrapped in sumproduct:

```
=sumproduct(B7:B12,sumif(E:E,C7:C12,F:F))
```

Comment: this is great, works too. Thank you Tom! Is even better than using Vlookup as no hardcoding of the column i.e. more robust to change in format of the sheet where I do have the exchange rate. Making my day.

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(VLOOKUP(B1:B6,D1:E2,2,1)*A1:A6)
```

works in Google Sheet instead of

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B7:B12,SUMIFS(F:F,E:E,C7:C12))
```